# Template pointer to a member function - getter

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, getter, member

So i'm making a sorting function and i want it to sort my elements depending on the getter i give it.
The problem is my getter is `const` and thats why my current code doesn't work. If i remove `const` it works just fine.

```
struct User {
    string name;
    string getX() const { return name; } //// doesnt work with this
    string getX() { return name; }       //// this works fine. but i need my getter to be const
};

template <typename ElemType, typename MemberType>
void _sort(std::vector<ElemType>& vec, MemberType(ElemType::* member)(), bool ascending = true)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < vec.size() - 1; ++j)
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size() - j - 1; ++i)
            if (((vec[i].*member)() < (vec[i + 1].*member)()) ^ ascending)
                swap(vec[i], vec[i + 1]);
}

int main()
{
    vector<User> a{ User{"Z"}, User{"E"}, User{"B"}, User{"R"}, User{"A"} };

    for (auto e : a)
        cout << e.name << " ";
    cout << endl;

    _sort(a, &User::getX);

    for (auto e : a)
        cout << e.name << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What do i do to make it work with `const` getter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make the parameter const as well:

```
template <typename ElemType, typename MemberType>
void _sort(std::vector<ElemType>& vec, MemberType(ElemType::* member)() const, bool ascending = true)
________________________________________________________________________^^^^^
```

Or don't make the parameter that specific:

```
template <typename ElemType, typename MemberType>
void _sort(std::vector<ElemType>& vec, MemberType member, bool ascending = true)
```

The former won't work if the getter isn't const, while the latter will work with anything. If you pass the latter a function that cannot be called like `(vec[i].*member)()`, then the compilation error will be there instead of in the signature of `_sort`.

Comment: @MaximYarmolik • C++ is a hard language.  A complex language.  A very large language (core language + standard library).  It has a lot of sharp edges.  A lot of quirks.  A lot of odd syntax, because it make a herculean effort for backwards compatibility.  A well-used, popular language -- which is both a blessing (lots of resources; you can get a job using it) and a curse (the language is "held back" for legacy concerns; evolution beholden to a chorus of voices & concerns).

Comment: i understand:) but this moment was very obvious. i dont even know why i didnt think of that. i just needed to put the word in the same spot